# Does the plot of $(1,X_{(1)}), (2,X_{(2)}), \cdots, (n,X_{(n)})$ has a name?

Tags: data-visualization, order-statistics

Consider a sample of $n$ observations from a random variable $X$. I am plotting

$$(1,X_{(1)}), (2,X_{(2)}), \cdots, (n,X_{(n)}) $$

where $X_{(i)}$ is the k$th$ [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of $X$. Does this plot/curve has a name? It might be a type of [Rankit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankit) graph, but I am not sure. It seems not to be a Q-Q plot or a P-P plot.

(Updated after Dilip and Scortchi provided further ideas)

Comment: What does the line look like between the top of one head and the top of the next head? A ramp? Flat across one body width and then jumping at the point of contact of the shoulders from one height to the next?

Comment: @DilipSarwate That was just an example of what I am thinking of. Those details are not relevant. For a large $n$, the graph is continuous.

Comment: "For a large $n$, the graph is continuous". Nonsense!

Comment: I should have said, the graph looks like continuous (and so those details are not relevant). Why the downvote? So bad is the question?

Comment: Yes, I do think the question does not show any effort on your part, not in the asking, not in the illustrative example, and not in the follow-up discussion. If $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are the sample values, you have told us that the points $(X_{(1)},X_{(1)}), (X_{(2)},X_{(2)}), \ldots, (X_{(n)},X_{(n)})$ are on the "curve" you are trying to draw. (Here, $X_{(k)}$ is the $k$-th _order statistic)._ What _other_ points are on the curve? All the known points are on the _straight line_ $y=x$, and so what is crucial is the behavior of the curve _between_ the known points; a matter that you blow off

Comment: @DilipSarwate Points are not on the straight line. Say my sample is $n=3$, with observations 4, 5, and 5.5 (foot). The plot include three points: (1,4), (2,5), (3,5.5). That is not a straight line along $y=x$. As $n$ goes very large, the points can be approximated with a continuous curve (the kernel, if you wish).

Comment: So it's a plot of $(1, X_{(1)}) , (2, X_{(2)}), \ldots, (n, X_{(n)})$? It'd help to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Scortchi Done.

Comment: It's a quantile plot with rank as one coordinate. It's a rank-size plot. Neither name rules out others. Either name is consistent with other names and there are several

Comment: I have not found online an example of such plot when searching "rank-size plot". Can you provide an example in which such plot is produced?

Comment: Thanks! It's essentially a plot of the empirical distribution function with the axes transposed.

Comment: @Scortchi Mmm, so its a flipped graph of the (empirical) CDF of $X$, with the uniform side of the axis expanded by $n$?

Comment: Rank-size plot is a standard term in studies of (e.g.) city size distributions.  I don't especially like the term because rank is usually on the horizontal axis, but that's not the question. The term quantile plot goes back at least to Wilk and Gnanadesikan _Biometrika_ 1968. All quantile plots are quantile-quantile plots: here the ranks are just (the quantiles of) a uniform distribution on the integers 1 to $n$. Quantile function (some mathematical nuances aside) is a direct name for the inverse cumulative distribution function.

Comment: The direct term _quantile plot_ is used by W.S. Cleveland and others.  Where the emphasis is on showing the data directly, it seems to me a good term. Where the emphasis is on comparison with a brand-name distribution, or with another sample, quantile-quantile plot as a term clearly makes sense too.